# Ruby multithreading queues

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

I have a problem with synchronizing threads, I have no idea how to do it, can someone help me ?

So, the thing is that I have to launch the threads in some specific order.
The order is the following:

Threads 1 and 7 can go simultaneously, and after one of them is finished, the next thread is launched (i.e. thread 2 or/and thread 6), the same way goes with thread 3 and 5.
And the last one, after both thread 3 and 5 are finished running, goes the last one, thread 4.

This is the code, I had begun with, but I am stuck at the queue implementation somehow.

```
MUTEX          = Mutex.new
high_condition = ConditionVariable.new
low_condition  = ConditionVariable.new
threads = []

7.times do |i|
  threads << Thread.new{
    MUTEX.synchronize {
      Thread.current["number"] = i

      you_shall_not_pass
    }
  }
end

threads.map(&:join)

def you_shall_not_pass
  order = Thread.current["number"]
end
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the expected output and what you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: The expected output can be something like:
`
Thread1 has accomplished its task
Thread2 has accomplished its task
Thread7 has accomplished its task
Thread3 has accomplished its task
Thread6 has accomplished its task
Thread5 has accomplished its task
Thread4 has accomplished its task
`

The output doesn't really matter, the problem is to launch them in an appopriate way

Comment: Is this a real rquirement, or some exercise?

Comment: more of an exercise, that will help in some later workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ruby's [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Queue.html) as a [counting semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). It has blocking `push` and `pop` operations that you can use to hand out a limited number of tokens to threads, requiring that each thread acquire a token before it runs and release the token when it's finished. If you initialize the queue with 2 tokens, you can ensure only 2 threads run at a time, and you can create your threads in whatever order you like.

```
require 'thread'

semaphore = Queue.new
2.times { semaphore.push(1) } # Add two concurrency tokens

puts "#{semaphore.size} available tokens"

threads = []
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4].each do |i|
  puts "Enqueueing thread #{i}"
  threads << Thread.new do
    semaphore.pop # Acquire token
    puts "#{Time.now} Thread #{i} running. #{semaphore.size} available tokens. #{semaphore.num_waiting} threads waiting."
    sleep(rand(10)) # Simulate work
    semaphore.push(1) # Release token
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)

puts "#{semaphore.size} available tokens"
```

```
$ ruby counting_semaphore.rb
2 available tokens
Enqueueing thread 1
Enqueueing thread 7
2015-12-04 08:17:11 -0800 Thread 7 running. 1 available tokens. 0 threads waiting.
2015-12-04 08:17:11 -0800 Thread 1 running. 0 available tokens. 0 threads waiting.
Enqueueing thread 2
Enqueueing thread 6
2015-12-04 08:17:11 -0800 Thread 2 running. 0 available tokens. 0 threads waiting.
Enqueueing thread 3
Enqueueing thread 5
Enqueueing thread 4
2015-12-04 08:17:19 -0800 Thread 6 running. 0 available tokens. 3 threads waiting.
2015-12-04 08:17:19 -0800 Thread 5 running. 0 available tokens. 2 threads waiting.
2015-12-04 08:17:21 -0800 Thread 3 running. 0 available tokens. 1 threads waiting.
2015-12-04 08:17:22 -0800 Thread 4 running. 0 available tokens. 0 threads waiting.
2 available tokens
```